# Android Wear App Crash in Moto 360 in other watches app is working fine

Tags: android, crash, wear-os, moto-360, wearables

I am working on wear application. Application is working fine in other watches but in Moto 360 it is getting crashed as we launch application.
Android wear 1.5.0, OS: 6.0.1,Google Play service 11.0.55.
Here is the logs.

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-06 12:48:54.471 5752-5752/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.google.android.wearable.app, PID: 5752
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getHeight()' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3831)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3849)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getHeight()' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.google.android.clockwork.home.cuecard.VoicePlateFragment.onCueCardClosed(VoicePlateFragment.java:1734)
                                                 at com.google.android.clockwork.home.cuecard.VoiceUiController.close(VoiceUiController.java:440)
                                                 at com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity.removeCueCard(HomeActivity.java:1720)
                                                 at com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity.destroyCueCard(HomeActivity.java:876)
                                                 at com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity.onDestroy(HomeActivity.java:908)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6422)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1142)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3818)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3849) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-06 12:48:54.480 467-933/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home.HomeActivity
07-06 12:48:54.745 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: On entry to LockedInner, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1
07-06 12:48:54.745 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: after finishPostLayoutPolicyLw, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x0
07-06 12:48:54.746 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: mLayoutNeeded, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1
07-06 12:48:54.746 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: On entry to LockedInner, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1
07-06 12:48:54.747 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: after finishPostLayoutPolicyLw, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x0
07-06 12:48:54.753 467-508/? V/WindowManager: Layouts looping: mLayoutNeeded, mPendingLayoutChanges = 0x1
07-06 12:48:54.754 467-508/? E/WindowManager: Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping
07-06 12:48:54.760 467-508/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.us.lexusenformremote/.Splash: +602ms
07-06 12:48:54.975 5359-5359/? I/CmaSystemUpdateService: ActiveReceiver: Intent { act=android.os.UpdateLock.UPDATE_LOCK_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateServiceActiveReceiver (has extras) }
07-06 12:48:54.975 5359-5359/? I/CmaSystemUpdateService: receiver: Intent { act=android.os.UpdateLock.UPDATE_LOCK_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateServiceActiveReceiver (has extras) }
07-06 12:48:55.004 213-5984/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = voice-rec-dmic-ef-fluence
07-06 12:48:55.008 213-343/? D/audio_hw_primary: adev_close_input_stream: 0xb410f1e0
```

Comment: Please post your code around VoicePlateFragment.java:1734

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is not part of my code. This is part of some system watch face.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been opened in [this google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/android-wear/fqDZFs24e0A/kVHax2vZkuwJ) and the device was moto 360 as well. Here's the engineer's response:

> There are many reasons why your Android Wear watch might show the
>   message “Android Wear has stopped”.
>
> 1. Make sure you are on the [latest Android Wear app update](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en).
> 2. Make sure you are on the latest Android Wear watch update
> 3. Try restarting your watch
> 4. If none of this works, then [try  unpairing and pairing again](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056905?hl=en&vid=0-166481431760-1499415330080).
>
> If none of this is not working, you might try other solutions users in
>   this thread used succesfully.
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Apps > Android Wear - Clear Cache and Clear Data. See if this helps.
> 2. Update Google app on your Android phone or iPhone
> 3. Check 3rd party apps and watch faces recently installed. Try uninstalling from phone and then reboot both watch and phone.
> 4. From Settings, Device, Apps, use the Uninstall updates button to back out the latest changes to Google Play Services, Then Clear cache
>      and Clear data. There could be a problem with the latest update of
>      Google play Services.
> 5. If you have problem with some specific manufacturer or you suspect it might be a Hardware issue, please contact them
> 6. Check steps on [how to fix an app that is not working](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2668665?vid=0-166481431760-1499415330080).